# upgrading from fckeditor to ckeditor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, fckeditor

I have some old code that i need to update quickly, i need to replace the old fckeditor with the new ckeditor. here's my javascript for calling fckeditor

```
<script type="text/javascript">
{
    function swap_to_wysiwyg_short_description()
    {
        var oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor( 'short_description' ) ;
        oFCKeditor.BasePath = 'fckeditor/' ;
        oFCKeditor.Value = 'This is some <strong>sample text</strong>. You are using <a href="http://www.fckeditor.net/">FCKeditor</a>.' ;
        document.getElementById('short_description_button').style.visibility = "hidden";
        oFCKeditor.ReplaceTextarea() ;
    }
}
</script>
```

this calls the javascript file:

```
fckeditor/fckeditor.js
```

i'm thinking instead of changing all my html files i could just edit fckeditor and make this call ckeditor?

here's the new code to call ckeditor:

```
<script>

        CKEDITOR.replace( 'short_description', {
filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/store/admin/kcfinder/browse.php',
filebrowserUploadUrl: '/store/admin/kcfinder/upload.php'
});

    </script>
```

How can i alter fckeditor/fckeditor.js to call ckeditor without having to change all my html pages?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for future you should make one function to call your wysiwyg editor and put there your code. You will make that work once and in future there will be no problem with changing editor to other one.